# How to set text from bundle (toolbar)

Tags: java, android, toolbar

How to set text from bundle (toolbar) I have no idea how to set it.

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColor">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="My example"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

DetailActivity.java

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle!=null){
            String name = bundle.getString("nameCar");
        }

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.m_tool_bar_detail);
        TextView textToolbar = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textView_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){

            textToolbar.setText(name); ///ERROR(name)
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_name));
        }
```

I've tried `textToolbar.setText("xxxxx");` but it gives an error.

I want to get `name` in bundle to set `Textview` in toolbar.

Comment: The variables that are defined within a block are not accessible outside that block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get name in bundle to set Textview in toolbar

You should set `String` name as global.

```
String name = null;
```

Then

```
if (bundle!=null){
     name = bundle.getString("nameCar");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` variable is inaccessible outside the `if` block and you should be getting a warning in there. Move that variable outside the `if` block and you should be fine

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = null;

    if (bundle != null){
        name = bundle.getString("nameCar");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**No need for bundle for Single text transfer.**

step 1.Put content(write a code put string value in first activity)

```
    String strnamecar="Maruti";
    Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("nameCar",strnamecar);
    startActivity(intent);
```

step 2.getcontent(get a string value in next activity)

```
     Intent carintent=getIntent();
     if(carintent!=null){
        String str=carintent.getStringExtra("nameCar");
     }
```

**If u need Bundle then using this**

step 1.Put content(write a code put string value in first activity)

```
    String strnamecar="Maruti";
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putString("nameCar",strnamecar);
    Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("nameCar",strnamecar);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
```

step 2.getcontent(get a string value in next activity)

```
    Intent carintent=getIntent();
    if(carintent!=null){
        Bundle getb=carintent.getExtras();
        String str=getb.getString("nameCar");
    }
```